# Python: Getting mocked function value returned, not MagicMock, without adding returnvalue

Tags: python, mocking

So, basically I want to mock a function imported in another class, and for some reason I can't retrieve the mocked result without calling returnvalue of the mock.

This is the setup: one file, one module, one test class. I want to mock functionB() in source.fileB.

**source.fileB**

```
def functionB():
    print('toto')
```

**source.fileA**

```
from source.fileB import *

def functionA():
    print("bar")
    return functionB()
```

**Test case**

```
from source.fileA import functionA
from source.fileA import functionB

@mock.patch('source.fileA.functionB')
def test_functionA(functionB_mock):
 functionB_mock().returnvalue = "foo"

 print(functionB_mock) # prints MagicMock object named functionB
 print(functionB_mock.returnvalue) # prints MagicMock object name functionB.returnvalue
 print(functionB_mock().returnvalue) #prints "foo"
 print(functionA().returnvalue) #executes functionA, prints both "bar" and "foo"
 print(functionA()) #executes functionA, prints both "bar" and MagicMock object named functionB()
```

So every time I try to get the result of the mocked functionB(), I have to use returnvalue. This is driving me nuts as I cannot update functionA() with

```
return functionB().returnvalue
```

in order for the rest of the code under test to execute properly.
I must be doing something wrong, but I can't understand what precisely.

Comment: `functionB_mock().returnvalue = "foo"` should be `functionB_mock.returnvalue = "foo"`.  When you call `functionB_mock()` it's returning a *different* `Mock` object (because the default return value of a `Mock` is another `Mock`, just like every attribute of a `Mock` is another `Mock`), and setting the `return_value` of that second `Mock` won't affect your `functionA` caller.

Comment: Thanks for helping. 
With 'functionB_mock.returnvalue = "foo"' I get these results:  
 `print(functionB_mock) # prints MagicMock object named functionB`
 `print(functionB_mock.returnvalue) # prints "foo"`

I still don't get why print(functionB_mock) won't print "foo". And why the rest of the code under test retrieves a MagicMock object, not "foo". 
(sorry I'm a bit struggling with comment formatting...)

Comment: If you want `print(functionB_mock)` to print `foo` then you need to do `functionB_mock = 'foo'`, but I'm pretty sure you don't actually want that because then `functionB_mock` locally points to a string, not a Mock.  :)

Comment: duh, I just realized you typo'd `return_value` as `returnvalue` (and I copied and pasted your typo).  Make that change and things will make more sense.  :)

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much for pointing it out, I just spent so much time on this.... It now works like a charm. It seemed so simple to use, yet I could not find a way to make it work... Thank you @Samwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The mock attribute you want is `return_value`, not `returnvalue`!
2. You need to set that attribute on the mock itself, not the result of calling the mock (which is a different mock).

Here's a self-contained (single-file) version of your test code with the fix and some explanatory comments.

```
import mock


def functionB():
    print('toto')


def functionA():
    print("bar")
    return functionB()


@mock.patch('__main__.functionB')
def test_functionA(functionB_mock):
    functionB_mock.return_value = "foo"

    # Prints a mock object because that's what functionB_mock is.
    print(functionB_mock)

    # Prints "foo" because that's what functionB_mock returns.
    print(functionB_mock())

    # The following two lines would raise AttributeError because
    # "foo" isn't a Mock and doesn't have a 'return_value' attribute!
    # print(functionB_mock().return_value)
    # print(functionA().return_value)

    # Executes functionA, prints "bar" and "foo"
    print(functionA())


test_functionA()
```